# Passing system properties to Jetty runner through command line

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, system-properties

I've a web application that runs with jetty. I include a client.jar in this web application for a functionality. client.jar needs a system property -Dconfig with location to the properties file. How do I pass this to when I start my application using jetty-runner ? I could only find setting it through jetty.xml but I'm trying to find if there is a way through command line.

Comment: Might want to post a few command line techniques you have already tried.

Comment: I've no idea how to do this through command line. I did not find it anywhere. I'm trying with jetty.xml as of now.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution to pass property through command line. I fixed this by passing below file jetty.xml to command line as below. I'm posting it here as it may help someone.

```
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Denv=$1 -jar $LIB_PATH/jetty-runner-*.jar --config $CONF_PATH/jetty.xml $DIST_PATH/my-app*.war &
```

jetty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperties">
        <Arg>
            <New class="java.util.Properties">
                <Call name="putAll">
                    <Arg>
                        <Call class="java.lang.System" name="getProperties" />
                    </Arg>
                </Call>
                <Call name="setProperty">
                    <Arg>iamconfig</Arg>
                    <Arg>iamclient.properties</Arg>
                </Call>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our project, we have used below set of code to set system property while doing jetty:run

```
 clean compile -Dcurrent.region=AIR jetty:run
```